# How to rig a character to a scooter?

Tags: rigging

I have a moving character rigged to a scooter (the scooter object is parented to the right foot bone).
Now the hands are not synchron with the handlebar: hands and handle are moving differently.
I don't know how to make that right, how to rig the character synchron - so that the hands stick with the handle and the right foot with the base of the scooter.

Thank you in advance for any help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: you need to do the opposite, parent the bones of the character to the scooter with some Child Bone constraints

Comment: thank you! i tried "Child of" in Bone Constraints tab but it doesn´t change anything..

Comment: actually you should simply parent the whole armature to the scooter, and parent each hand controller to the handlebar but maybe share your file?

Comment: ok, i´m trying to upload! file is 29,2 MB but i always get the error message: Uploaded blend files can be no larger than 30 MB

Comment: Use workupload for example, or remove the character object, only keep the scooter and armature

Comment: ok now it works..[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=sXqBe9zN" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/sXqBe9zN/)  looks like something is broken here..

Comment: thank you! problem is the hip has to move because the body goes up and down (for the left leg has to touch the ground once in acircle)..is it possible to only have the right foot stick to the scooter (and the hands to the handle) ?

Comment: Edit: Actually the problem is that you want to keep an action but the foot is the bone that is supposed to stay still on the scooter but it's moving so I'm not sure how you can easily fix that

Comment: I don't know how you could fix that, to make the foot stick to a reference point it means that each frame you need to move and rotate the master bone called mixamorig:Hips until the foot is still from frame 1 to the end, seems impossible to me but I may miss a solution

Comment: thank you anyway! i will try some things (having everything, except the left leg, static for example..)

Answer (score 0):

I think i found a way:

"Copy location" in Bone Constraints (hand bone to an empty parented to the handle )